# How does Thread.interrupted() work in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, static-methods

`Thread.interrupted()` is static method. Then how it is able to modify the interrupted flag of instance objects?

---

This question is not duplicate of

- [How exactly does Thread.interrupt() and Thread.interrupted() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928970/how-exactly-does-thread-interrupt-and-thread-interrupted-work)
- [What does java.lang.Thread.interrupt() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do)

because they don't address the question mentioned in the description of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo some details, it looks like you could write your own Thread.interrupted() as essentially:

```
static boolean interrupted ( ) {
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    return me.isInterrupted();
}
```

So the real question is how does the static function `Thread.currentThread()` find the current thread?  This appears to be a bit of an unsolved mystery: [How does Thread.currentThread() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527557/how-does-thread-currentthread-work) :)  Serious answer: it's specific to the JVM and how threads are implemented.

Comment: Except that `interrupted()` resets the flag and `isInterrupted()` does not